# How to encode the same vectors in a 2D list to the same value？

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

For example, if I have a 2D list like this:

```
a = [[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,2], [0,2], [1,0]]
```

For the list `a` above:

```
a[0]=a[1]=a[2]=[0,0]
a[3]=a[4]=[0,2]
```

I hope to convert `a` as `[0,0,0,1,1,2]`
That is to say, the same element will be marked with the same value（the element here is a 1D list）

Is there any way to in pytorch or numpy?

Comment: Please provide more explanation. What does "for list `a`: `a[0]=a[1]=a[2] ...`" mean?

Comment: If you mean to say that the first 3 elements of `a` are the same, then why are they *not*. the same in the definition you provide for `a`? Or are they _supposed_ to be considered the same? If so, why?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: @zihao are the identical elements successive or in any order? what would an example of input/output for a different order?

Comment: The above 2D list "a" has five 1D lists, including [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,2], [0,2], [1,0]; Each 1D list is made up of 2 values (the value can be ranged from 0 to 500). The identical elements means list1==list2. The aim is to find all identical elements in the 2D list and labeled them as different values.

Comment: Then you want `import numpy as np ; np.unique(a, axis=0, return_inverse=True)[1]`

Comment: That's exactly what I want!  Thank you for your answer sincerely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy isn't really my forte but I think this will give you the results you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np

keys, index = np.unique(a, axis = 0, return_inverse = True)
index
```

This works by calling `numpy.unique` on your input list across its first axis, which will compare each of the sub-lists. I used the `return_inverse` argument to instruct the function to return the indices of the unique array to which each sublist corresponds. This code preserves the order in `index` and the unique keys in `keys`. By doing `keys[index]`, you can actually reconstruct the original array.